# Create a list of models from a list of data from documents

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My flutter app is going to have a feed of posts from users. I have posts in my firebase firestore database from my swift app that I am going to replace. So for I have this in my flutter fetch posts function:

```
    final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

        final QuerySnapshot result = await userRef.get();

        result.docs.forEach((res) async {
          print(res.id);
          QuerySnapshot posts = await userRef.doc(res.id).collection("posts").get();

          posts.docs.forEach((res) {
            print(res.data());
          });
        });
```

So with this function, I can print a list of the data of all of each users posts. Here is a part of the print:

```
flutter: {postedDate: Oct 24, 2021 at 6:10 AM, id: twentyonepilots_354_1635073829.595439, caption: , likers: [], postUrlString: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/globe-e8b7f.appspot.com/o/twentyonepilots%2Fposts%2Ftwentyonepilots_354_1635073829.595439.png?alt=media&token=48b6b1bc-112b-4d61-84ee-3847ba8dce94}
flutter: {postedDate: 13 Aug 2021, 9:54 AM, id: viktoria_923_1628837663.179892, caption: just posted, feeling good :), likers: [anelia, globetester, alis, devil, vladyynk, fllcuriie, HackerX, nihilistic, imherefromtiktok, donnasmithofficial, hhhh, sachiq], postUrlString: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/globe-e8b7f.appspot.com/o/viktoria%2Fposts%2Fviktoria_923_1628837663.179892.png?alt=media&token=634ff70e-028c-4452-8c2b-b598eb8b8e48}
flutter: {postedDate: 21. Nov 2021 at 18:34, id: timsbs_464_1637516088.259705, caption: Hi https://google.com, likers: [timsbs], postUrlString: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/globe-e8b7f.appspot.com/o/timsbs%2Fposts%2Ftimsbs_464_1637516088.259705.png?alt=media&token=4ce3bf4d-3187-4ee9-954a-dc39532694ae}
```

How can I turn this list into a list of this post model?:

```
class Post {
  String id = "";
  String caption = "";
  String postUrlString = "";
  Timestamp postedDate = Timestamp.now();

  Post(
      {required this.id,
      required this.caption,
      required this.postUrlString,
      required this.postedDate});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a 'fromJson' method to Post class like below.

```
      final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

      final QuerySnapshot result = await userRef.get();

      List<Post> listPosts = [];

      result.docs.forEach((res) async {
        print(res.id);
        QuerySnapshot posts = await userRef.doc(res.id).collection("posts").get();

        posts.docs.forEach((res) {
          listPosts.add(Post.fromJson(res.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
        });

        print(listPosts);
      });
```

```
class Post {
  final String id;
  final String caption;
  final String postUrlString;
  final Timestamp postedDate;

  Post(
      {required this.id,
      required this.caption,
      required this.postUrlString,
      required this.postedDate});
  
  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : id = json['id'],
      caption = json['caption'],
      postUrlString = json['postUrlString'],
      postedDate = json['postedDate'] != null ? Timestamp.fromDate(json['postedData']) : Timestamp.now();

  @override
  String toString() => '''Post { id: $id,
     caption: $caption,
     postUrlString: $postUrlString
     postedData: $postedData
  }''';
}
```

Comment: I added 'as Map<String,dynamic>' casting code. Try again with changed code

Comment: Thanks there's no errors now but when I use this code and the print `listPosts`, I just get `#1      DatabaseManager.fetchPosts.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:globe_flutter/services/database.dart:26:30)
#2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:410:8)
#3      DatabaseManager.fetchPosts.<anonymous closure> (package:globe_flutter/services/database.dart:24:20)
<asynchronous suspension>` printed a bunch of times (once for each post). I'm not sure if this means the code didn't work or if the list is just not printable.

Comment: Would you try again with comment out code that 'another way'?

Comment: With the other way, when printing `listPosts` I get this printed... `[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'
#0      new Post.fromJson (package:globe_flutter/models/post.dart:32:45)
#1      DatabaseManager.fetchPosts.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:globe_flutter/services/database.dart:29:61)
#2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
#3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
` (next comment for the rest)

Comment: `#4      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)
#5      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#6      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:51:28)
#7      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:213:44)
#8      DatabaseManager.fetchPosts.<anonymous closure> (package:globe_flutter/services/database.dart:29:107)
<asynchronous suspension>`

Comment: 'postedData = json['postedData'] != null ? Timestamp.parse(json['postedData']) : Timestamp.now();' is modified. I wonder whether 'postedDate' is null. But null exists....

Comment: I just found another error that might be causing the issue. On this line `postedDate = Timestamp.parse(json['postedData']);` of `Post.fromJson`, there is an error which says "The method 'parse' isn't defined for the type 'Timestamp'.". I think it's because `timestamp` is a firebase property not flutter.

Comment: Sorry for that error. Because I cannot run my code with firestore by myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240518/discussion-between-globe-and-kuku).